# WPF TabControl: a dictionary for tab headers

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I've got a TabControl that is bound to its viewmodel Items property:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
```

This is the viewmodel class:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<object> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<object>();
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Items.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Alan", LastName = "Turing" });
        Items.Add(new Car() { ModelName = "Fiesta", Manifacturer = "Ford" });
    }

}
```

`Items`'s type is `ObservableCollection<object>`; this is because each tab represents a *different* kind of object, in this example a Person and a Car.

#### Question

I want to bind the tab's header to a text that is not available as a property of the bound classes, let say a manually provided header.
For example, I would like the first tab to have the text "Person" as header and the second to have the text "Car" as header:

[image: Person And Car As Tab's Headers]

I thought of:

- adding the Header property to each class. It's easy and straightforward from the binding point of view, but this is sort of a generalized viewer and not all the interfaces of the input data can be modified.
- an "attached property" would still require to act at class-level; yet feasible but probably a bit overkill
- A `Dictionary<object, string>` defined at the viewmodel level, let's call it Headers.
  Each time i add an object to the collection, i would also add an Header to the Headers dictionary. Its key would be the object itself.

  ```
  Person p = new Person() { FirstName = "Alan", LastName = "Turing" };
  Headers.Add(p, "Person");
  Items.Add(p);
  ```

But how to write the binding expression then?

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding ????????}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Even if possible, this solution seems to be not very 'binding-friendly'.

There seems to be two problems here: dynamically attach an information to an instance, and access it via binding.

Any ideas?

#### Postscript - the code

The code, for completeness.
My classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    public string Manifacturer { get; set; }
}
```

My DataTemplate, defined in the `<Winodow.Resources>` tag.

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="{Binding FirstName}"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding LastName}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Car}">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="{Binding Manifacturer}"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding ModelName}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I would for sure just use a [IValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter?view=netframework-4.8) to convert the object to the proper header.

Comment: Alternative would also be a [`HeaderTemplateSelector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.headeredcontentcontrol.headertemplateselector?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Controls_HeaderedContentControl_HeaderTemplateSelector). You could then decide based on type.

Comment: how about a Dictionary<string, object> called Items? Then in header you bind to Key, in tab you can use content presenter bound to Value.

Answer (score 1):

You can also override the `ToString()` method for your model classed and return your friendly name from there.

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Person";
    }
}
```

**Template**

```xml
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```